# Date picker in activity problem

Tags: android

I need to put a control on my activity ( not a popup ) for choosing date. I read on net but all examples are with dialog, but I don't need that. Is there any embedded control in Android for that ? Does anybody have example for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DatePicker` widget. Developers tend to use the dialog because `DatePicker` is huge.